# Does Bridge design pattern have only one abstract and interface Class in Java?

Tags: java, design-patterns, bridge

I am really difficult to think about  abstract and interface Class in Java?

Here an example :
We have 2 users which have the same and  different action in School system
Teacher : *can add exercise* and **view the exercise**
Student : can **view** and *submit exercise*
We have 2 different of user, different action and the same action.
So how can we make it to one abstract class and interface?

Comment: I would use Teacher and Student as two different classes.

Comment: The answer to the question in the title is _no_. The Bridge design pattern is not a solution to this problem.

Comment: I'd look into [RBAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Role-based_access_control) for this and assign users roles when the log in. You could have a base class called User with two derived classes, Student and Teacher. Whether you need the common base class depends on whether Users share common code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should not be only one class - things that behave differently should be represented by different classes.

If you want to use an interface and an abstract class...

Create an interface for the shared behaviour:

```
interface ExerciseViewer {
    void view(Exercise exercise);
}
```

Then create concrete classes for each type of person that extends an abstract base class:

```
abstract class SchoolPerson implements ExerciseViewer {
    public void view(Exercise exercise) {
         // some implemention
    }
}

class Teacher extends SchoolPerson {
    public void add(Exercise exercise) {
        // some implementation
    }
}

class Student extends SchoolPerson {
    public void submit(Exercise exercise) {
        // some implementation
    }
}
```

However, I would not do it this way. Instead, I would create the two concrete classes that implement ExerciseViewer that has no methods (see [*marker interface*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marker_interface_pattern)), an Exercise class and a separate ExerciseService class that handles the actions with appropriate parameter types.